# debugging step by step android system (audioflinger)

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-debug

I'm currently working on an android rom, and i would want to know if it's possible to debug some part of the system with debug tools like gdb?...

Or do you know how contributors that propose/add patch to the android source code test there own code (other that with log and alog)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging Java framework services (i.e. the services in system_server process) is different from debugging native processes (i.e. processes like surfaceflinger). If the code you want to debug is a framework native library loaded by one of the above apps, you will need a different method to debug it.

Please check [Android framework debugging techniques](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/) articles.

Comment: you my friend are late.. but it's a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdbserver in the phone/target.

```
  gdbserver :1234 --attach pid
```

arm-linux-androideabi-gdb on the client.  On gdb prompt, type:

```
  target remote ip:1234
```

Comment: the fact that some part of the android source are compiled with optimization flags would not be in the way?

Comment: @CollioTV  You're right.   I do build my own platform code.